# 画面描画時に StackOverflowError が発生する

Tags: android, java, android-layout

Android2.x 系の端末にて、Activity のレイアウト XML に`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` を適用したところ、下記のような `StackOverflowError` が発生して強制終了します。

同様の不具合情報を探していたところ、レイアウト階層が深すぎて発生するという問題という情報があり、原因特定の手段として試験的に一階層下げてみましたが、やはり同様の異常終了が発生してしています。

`DrawerLayout` を使用しなければ発生しないため、これに起因することは間違いないのですが、有効な手段がわかっていない状況です。 (現状これ以上の階層構造を変更することも難しい状況でもあります)

上記問題について、有効な手段をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。

```
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:1026)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.getChars(SpannableStringInternal.java:70)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:69)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.Layout$Ellipsizer.getChars(Layout.java:2155)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:69)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Canvas.java:1310)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.Styled.drawUniformRun(Styled.java:151)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:317)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:376)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1667)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:483)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4481)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7080)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7083)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6840)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6628)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1571)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1686)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3211)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7083)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3096)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7083)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:870)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7083)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7083)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7083)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
01-29 17:25:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(24284):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWind
```

Comment: スタックトレースを見る限りでは ViewGroup が大量にネストされているように見えるのですが、それを削減することもできないのでしょうか?

Comment: 問題の発生する layout xml を貼ってもらえると解決しやすいように思います

Answer (score 1):

android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayoutを使って、まずは単純なレイアウトを作成して
徐々に階層を深めていき、どの段階でstack overflowになるのかを調べ、
実際に使いたいコードとの差異を見ると原因が切り分けできるかもしれません。

・参考記事
layoutoptを用いて、レイアウトを最適化する
http://techbooster.jpn.org/andriod/application/8016/

Answer (score 0):

レイアウトが分からないので助けになるか全く分からないのですが、`<merge />`タグを活用する余地は無いでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayoutを使うと複雑なレイアウトでも少ない階層で実現できることが多いです。
使っていなければ試してみてください。